# Is this actually a js promise?

Tags: ajax, promise, knockout-2.0

I have this code in a javascript module (I'm using Require js and Knockout)

```
var getPersons = function(personsObservable) {
    personsObservable([]);
    var getOptions = {
        url: 'api/persons',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json'
    };

    return $.ajax(getOptions)
        .then(querySucceeded)
        .fail(queryFailed);

    function querySucceeded(data) {
        var persons = [];
        data.sort(sortPersons);
        data.forEach(function (item) {
            var p = new model.Person(item);
            persons.push(p);
        });

        personsObservable(persons);
    };
}
```

and then in another one using that module I call it like this:

```
function refresh() {
    return dataservice.getPersons(persons).then(dataservice.getTalks(talks));
};
```

being getTalks another function in the dataservice module.

But I'm not sure if the result of that will be an actual promise, i.e. until I populate persons with the result of the ajax call the getTalks won't be invoked. As far as I understood calling the then method will do the trick, is that right?

Thanks

UPDATE:

So after reading the answers and further investigating into these promises stuff I came up with this, don't know if makes sense

Now the getPersons and getTalks don't populate the observable but just return the arrays, and the refresh function looks like this:

```
function refresh() {
    return $.when(dataservice.getPersons(persons), dataservice.getTalks(talks))
                .then(
                        //Success
                        function (personArgs, talksArgs) {
                            persons(personArgs);
                            talks(talksArgs);
                        },
                        //Failure
                        function(){
                            logger.log("There's been an error retrieving the data");
                        });
 };
```

TI still need that this refresh returns a promise, so still doubting about it.

Comment: Probably, this `.then(dataservice.getTalks(talks))` should be `.then(function() {return dataservice.getTalks(talks)})`.  You need to pass a function reference that can be executed in the future.  You were executing it immediately and passing it's return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the function `getPersons` is well named, then it will do just that (get persons) and no more, and the two calls to `personsObservable` will be made at the point that `getPersons` is called.

`getPersons` would thus compact down to :

```
var getPersons = function () {
    return $.ajax({//return here to make the make the result of the $.ajax().then() chain available at the point where getPersons() is called.
        url: 'api/persons',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).then(function (data) {
        //sortPersons is presumably defined in an outer scope
        return data.sort(sortPersons).map(function (item) {//return here to make the mapped array available as the promised result of getPersons.
            return new model.Person(item);//return here to push elements onto the mapped array
        });
    });
};
```

*Note - to keep things clean and efficient, no assignments are made within the function*

and would be called, for example, as follows :

```
persons([]);
getPersons().then(persons).fail(queryFailed);
```

The entire promise chain (in shorthand) is thus `$.ajax().then().then().fail();`, but split such that the first two calls in the chain are inside `getPersons`, which returns an appropriate promise.

The use of `$.when()` in your `refresh` function makes things very slightly more complicated. With `getTalks` modified in the same way as `getPersons`, `refresh` could be written as follows :

```
function refresh () {
    persons([]);
    talks([]);//assumed
    return $.when(dataservice.getPersons(), dataservice.getTalks()).then(function (p, t) {
        persons(p);
        talks(t);
    }, function () {
        logger.log("There's been an error retrieving the data");
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks Roamer, it seems to work fine although I don't need to use the [0] in the arguments returned from the promises, I found that debugging, as the arrays returned are precisely the array of persons and talks

Comment: Ah OK, in that case I'd better edit my answer. That aspect of jQuery is enough to drive anyone nuts. It's really poorly documented.